# What is the [Sci/Num]Python equivalent to Matlabs "norminv" (Normal inverse cumulative distribution function)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, statistics, scipy

I am searching for a python equivalent of the [`norminv`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/norminv.html) function in Matlab.

Or in other words (from the above description):
I am searching for the "Normal inverse cumulative distribution function" in python, or probably in the stats part of scipy (Or maybe numpy?)

I would guess that it exists in scipy, but probably under another name than in matlab, or in matlabs help page. However I am not sure of this functions other names, or exact workings, so I am having a hard time finding it. And unfortunately it's not simply the "Inverse normal cumul…" instead of the "Normal inverse cumul…"

Answer (score 2):

It depends exactly on what you want.  If you want the `cdf` of a distribution that is the inverse of the normal distribution, you want [`invgauss`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.invgauss.html), "An inverse Gaussian continuous random variable.".  To get the `cdf`, you would need to use the `invgauss.cdf` method.  Adapted from the documentation:

```
from scipy.stats import invgauss
mu = 0.145462645553
vals = invgauss.ppf([0.001, 0.5, 0.999], mu)
res = invgauss.cdf(vals, mu)
```

On the other hand, if you want the inverse of the `cdf` of the normal distribution, you want the `ppf` method of the [`norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) distribution, which is the "Percent point function (inverse of cdf — percentiles)."

Comment: I don't think this is correct: [Inverse Gaussian Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution)

Comment: From the scipy 0.10.0 release notes: "The deprecated name `invnorm` was removed from `scipy.stats.distributions`, this distribution is available as `invgauss`."

Comment: I'm just not sure if the *inverse gaussian cdf* is the same as: *the inverse of the gaussian cdf*. I'm just cross checking this.

Comment: Ok. Reason why this must be incorrect: The inverse of the normal cumulative distribution function is a function defined on the interval `[0,1]`, whereas the distribution function of the so called *inverse gaussian distribution* has support `(0,Inf)` as listed on wikipedia. This means those must be two different things as I suspected. The OP wants the function `norm.ppf` used in the question I linked as duplicate.

Comment: Point taken.  I have expanded the answer to cover both possibilities.

Comment: Ah, you mentioned `ppf` while I was adding it to the answer.

Comment: *a distribution that is the inverse of the normal distribution* is still not correct. As I understand it the *inverse normal distribution* is not *the inverse of the normal distribution*. I think it is just some unfortunate way of naming it, as it has *some* relation to the gaussian distribution.

Comment: Damn, why are there so many functions that are all almost called the same, yet are called different in all their implementations… Unfortunately I dont have matlab, so I cant do some quick checks to see which of the python functions produces the same output as matlab. However I could install octave, which seems to have a [norminv](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/norminv.html) function. I'll play around with the various possibilities and report back.

Comment: OK, so assuming `norminv` in octave is indeed the same as `norminv` in matlab (Octaves documentation is quite short, and I suck at statistics) the python equivalent seems indeed to be `norm.ppf` from `scipy.stats`: octave-`octave:9> norminv(0.9)
ans =  1.2816
octave:10> norminv(0.5)
ans = 0` Python-`In [35]: stats.norm.ppf(0.9)
Out[35]: 1.2815515655446004

In [36]: stats.norm.ppf(0.5)
Out[36]: 0.0
`

Comment: I can confirm those two test cases with matlab `>> norminv(0.9) = 1.2816` `>> norminv(0.5) = 0`